# Sum value flow power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a table on azure following :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYxrk.jpg)

Can anyone help me to make a sum perday of number of users with flow power automate :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZskH.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you have a table in Azure, what exactly do you mean? Excel? Storage table? SQL?!? Can you confirm?

Comment: Hello,
It's azure table storage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a monster of an answer but it works so follow closely.

Refer to the images for what to do.

The basic concept is, loop through all entities and fill an array with the distinct row keys.  The way we determine if it's distinct or not is by adding the row key to an array **IF** it hasn't been added previously.

From there, we will loop through that distinct list and using an inner loop, we will sum each `NumberOfUsers` column **IF** the **Inner Row Key** matches the **Outer Row Key** that is being processed.

At the end of the outer loop, add an object to an array.  That object has two fields, "RowKey" and "NumberOfUsers".  The "NumberOfUsers" field contains the summation for that given RowKey.

From here, you have the distinct count.

If I've mis-used any fields (i.e. the use of RowKey) then change it up as need be.

This is just logic, you just need to apply it to the scenario.  I think this is best done in an Azure Function because it'll run faster and be a lot less to maintain but if you want to avoid that and use PowerAutomate, this works.

**Flow**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

**Data / Table**

[image: Table]

**Result**

[image: 20211208]

[image: 20211209]